# Fetch pivot table data in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4

I have created a pivot table `post_tag` and inserting data into it using sync method.

Now I want to fetch respective tags of a post to show in the view like following

```
{{ $post->tags }}
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now, you get object. Right ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your object to array. In laravel, you can use like this.

```
{{ $post->tags->toArray() }}
```

For more detail in [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json).

**Edit**

In your Post model.

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Tag'); // One to Many

    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag'); // Many to many
}
```

You can get like this.

```
$tags = Post::find($postId)->tags;
```

Or

```
$post = Post::find($postId);
$tags = $post->tags;
```

Hope it will be work for you.

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstand my question for my poor phrasing/quote.

it doesn't actually matter what I get object or array. I just want the access tag from the pivot to show in my view. How should I do that?